# Проблема с подсказками в querySelector если указан не тег

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Проблема в том что если в querySelector стоит тег,
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
то он выбрасывает подсказку,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
а если указать класс, то выбрасывает совсем другое. И это не очень удобно

PS: Дело не в плагинах, я их отрубил все

Answer (score 0):

Единственное что нашел.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Дело в том что

это конкретный html тэг.
Если мы знаем какой это тэг - мы знаем какие у него свойства, и что подсказывать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
а .li название класса которое может быть присвоено чему угодно, никто не знает что там у вас с таким классом будет, поэтому и подсказки не работают

Если более простым языком - иде может помочь только там где возможно точно предсказать что произойдет когда этот код выполнится.

Comment: Если вы хотите этого избежать, используйте тайп скрипт.